# how do I wire a 2nd Adafruit TMP117 board to my Adafruit Metro by I2C?

Tags: sensors, i2c, adafruit, temperature-sensor

I want to connect two TMP117 boards to one Metro (ie. Arduino).

(the first, addressed at 48 the 2nd at 49.)

Should 2nd board's 4 wires simply attach (ie. solder) in parallel to 1st board's 4 wires?
(ie. 3.3v, gnd, SCL, SDA)

background...
I want to read temperatures from two boards at once, in near real time and write to Windows file.

Comment: yes ...........

Answer (score 0):

You are correct almost. Connection in parallel is correct however you cannot read both at once, the bus supports talking to only device at a time. You will need to read one then the other. I do not know for sure if it is possible to get them to synchronize conversion but I think not.